# How can I return an item inside a tag in python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

I have the following code on a webpage:

```
<label data-correct="false">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="quizCtrl.state.selectedOptionForCurrentQuestion" ng-value="option" name="q0" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" value="[object Object]">

    <!--option image-->
    <!---->

    <!--option text-->
    <span ng-bind-html="quizCtrl.trustAsHtml(option.text)"><p>Earned three college degrees and supported himself as a small businessman - Google values entrepreneurship.</p></span>
</label>
<label data-correct="true">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="quizCtrl.state.selectedOptionForCurrentQuestion" ng-value="option" name="q0" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" value="[object Object]">

    <!--option image-->
    <!---->

    <!--option text-->
    <span ng-bind-html="quizCtrl.trustAsHtml(option.text)"><p>Has several years of work experience, and enjoys volunteering for Habitat for Humanity - Google values these character traits.</p></span>
</label>
<label data-correct="false">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="quizCtrl.state.selectedOptionForCurrentQuestion" ng-value="option" name="q0" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" value="[object Object]">

    <!--option image-->
    <!---->

    <!--option text-->
    <span ng-bind-html="quizCtrl.trustAsHtml(option.text)"><p>Recently graduated from Harvard University - Google is known for hiring the best and the brightest.</p></span>
</label>
<label data-correct="false">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="quizCtrl.state.selectedOptionForCurrentQuestion" ng-value="option" name="q0" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" value="[object Object]">

    <!--option image-->
    <!---->

    <!--option text-->
    <span ng-bind-html="quizCtrl.trustAsHtml(option.text)"><p>Worked as an independent contractor in different areas of the computer industry - Google values versatility.</p></span>
</label>
```

I want to target the data-correct field and if it's true the program should click it. This is what I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('label')
```

I'm quite new to python and selenium so I'm not sure what to do next

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [ i.get_attribute("data-correct") for i in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('label')]
```

data-correct is an attribute of the label element so you can use get_attribute given you are able locate the element correctly

if you are not concerned in getting the tag but about clicking it then use xpath  instead

```
[ i.click for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//label[@data-correct="true"]')]
```

but if clicking the element will cause stale element then you have to refind all elements .

use instead:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//label[@data-correct="true"]')

count = 0

while(count!=len(elems)):
    elems = WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(By.xpath,'//label[@data-correct="true"]'))
    elems[count].click()
    count+=1;
```

use webdriver wait if you have to :

```
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Is their a way to loop this? So that it tests all of the elements and not just the first one?

Comment: @jamjam46 Updated the answer

Comment: data will be a list containing the value

Comment: I also get this error when I run this ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'```

Comment: see the updated answer i didn't see that you where using fiind_elements , it will return a list so you have to use driver.find.elements_by..("something")[0].get_attribute . you have to get element from that array. i  updaated the answer this works as it ise

Comment: This returns the following list:
```[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: see if the locator is finding the correct label tag , try priniting get_attribute("outerHTML")

Comment: this prints the element , check if it is the label that you are interested in

Comment: oh can ya please write it in code for me? I think I messed it up. This is what I wrote:
```data = [i.get_attribute("data-correct") for i in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('label')]

print(data)
print(get_attribute("outerHTML"))
``` 
and my output is ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Studify.py", line 87, in <module>
    print(get_attribute("outerHTML"))
NameError: name 'get_attribute' is not defined```

Comment: just replace data-correct with outerHTML and see if elements are correct if it is not then correct it and then replace outerHTML with data-correct

Comment: ```outerHTML``` does give me results. But it doesn't show the true / false value. The ```data-correct``` simply returns a list that says None

Comment: Nvm I got it working. I just had to wait for the page to load

Comment: Now that I have them in a list do you know how I can get the program to click them on the browser?

Comment: what does that element do does it reloads something ?

Comment: @PDHide : This code will break if page gets refreshed after click.

Comment: thats why refinding the element in while loop

Comment: @PDHide : sorry I missed that part. +1